# Receiving issue: Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' trying to animate on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios-animations

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondVC = segue.destination as! SettingsViewController //error is marked here
    secondVC.transitioningDelegate = self
    secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
}

func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.transitionMode = .present
    transition.startingPoint = settingsButton.center
    transition.circleColor = UIColor.white

    return transition
}

func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.transitionMode = .dismiss
    transition.startingPoint = settingsButton.center
    transition.circleColor = UIColor.white

    return transition
}
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9sH_VxPPo4) to animate my Xcode application *using Swift*. I am running into the error of my SettingsViewController not being able to be cast as a UIViewController. I have checked out other questions with the same error but I have not found anything useful.

I am getting the error - SIGABRT: Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x7fff897a42b8) to 'Healthify.SettingsViewController' (0x107cd6a98)

Anyone know what I am doing wrong or experienced something similar?

Comment: The exception says that you have an instance of `UIViewController` not `SettingsViewController`. Check the custom class for your scene in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had embedded a UiViewController in the ViewController that was casting a UiViewController type to the SettingsViewController.

I did not need the UiViewController so I deleted it and the error went away.